# Safely hooking C functions into assembly

Tags: c, visual-studio, assembly, x86

I'm trying to put some C hooks into some code that someone else wrote in asm. I don't know much about x86 asm and I want to make sure I'm doing this safely.

So far I've got this much:

```
EXTERN _C_func

CALL _C_func
```

And that seems to work, but I'm sure that's dangerous as-is. At the very least it could be destroying EAX, and possibly more.

So I think all I need to know is: Which registers does C destroy and how do I ensure the registers are being saved properly? Is there anything else I can do to make sure I can safely insert hooks into arbitrary locations?

I'm using Visual Studio for the C functions, if that helps.
Thank you.

UPDATE:

I looked up the "paranoid" method several people suggested and it looks like this:

```
pushfd
pushad
call _C_func
popad
popfd
```

AD = (A)ll general registers

FD = (F)lags

(I'm not sure what the 'd' stands for, but it means 32-bit registers instead of 16-bit.)

But the most efficient method is illustrated in Kragen's answer below. (Assuming you don't need the preserve the flags. If you do, add the FD instructions.)

Also, be careful about allocating lots of stack variables in your C function as it could overrun the asm subroutine's stack space.

I think that about does it, thanks for you help everyone!

Comment: What is the signature of the C function?

Comment: Could you just save all registers and reload them after the call?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by signature, but the prototype would be void C_func(void); I'm not trying to pass arguments or use return values, if that's what you mean.

Comment: I don't see any reason why not. Which instructions should I use to do this? What about special registers like flags and floating point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the calling convention is cdecl and the signature of C_funct is simply:

```
void C_func(void);
```

Then that is perfectly "safe", however the registers EAX, ECX and EDX are "available for use inside the function", and so may be overwritten.

To protect against this you can save the registers that you care about and restore them afterwards:

```
push eax
push ecx
push edx

call _C_func

pop edx
pop ecx
pop eax
```

By convention the registers EBX, ESI, EDI, and EBP shouldn't be modified by the callee.

I believe that the flags may be modified by the callee - again if you care about preserving the value of flags then you should save them.

See the Wikipedia page on [x86 calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions).

Comment: @PhiS Erm yeah... thats a... erm... "new" register... :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to be aware of calling conventions. See this [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Caller_clean-up) for a discussion on calling conventions.

If you are paranoid about registers, you can always push all registers onto the stack before calling the function (functions shouldn't return without cleaning up, except for those registers that carry return information).

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on whether you are using an x86 or x86_64 platform ... the calling conventions for each, as well as the caller-save and callee-save registers (and even the available register set) are a bit different.

That being said, caller-save registers need to be pushed on the stack before you call your C-function.  Callee-save registers you don't need to worry about if you are calling a C-function, but you will need to pay attention to if you call an assembly routine from a C-function.

For a x86 32-bit platform, the caller-save registers are:

```
EAX
EDX
ECX
```

Also keep in mind that the stack-pointer registers, `ESP` and `EBP` will be changed as well with cdecl calling convention, but a C-function will restore those values after the call assuming you have not done something that a C-function would not expect you to-do with those registers.

The callee-save registers are:

```
EBX
ESI
EDI
```

Finally, the return value from your C-function is in the `EAX` register, and the C-function arguments are pushed onto the stack before calling the function.  The order in which that is done will depend on the calling convention, but for cdecl, that will be in right-to-left order, meaning the left-most argument to the C-function is pushed last on the stack before calling the function.

Should you decide to simply save all the general purpose registers on the stack before you call your C-function, and then pop them back off the stack after the C-function, you can do that on x86 using the `PUSHAD` and `POPAD` instructions.  These instructions are not useable on x86_64 though.  And also keep in mind that if you have a return value in `EAX`, you will need to-do something with that (like saving it in memory), before you call `POPAD`.

Comment: Wait a minute -- if ESP/EBP can be changed by callee, shouldn't I save those too? Otherwise they could be different after I return which could muck up the asm code which wasn't expecting me to interject a CALL instruction.

Comment: Sorry, I made a quick edit to clarify my point ... they are changed in the callee, but they should also be restored if you haven't done anything special with them.

Comment: Oh, I think I see--you're saying that the stacks may be used by the C function, one of the implications being that there needs to be enough stack space for the C function to use or whatnot.

Comment: Yes, although this is something to keep in mind should you ever decide to call an assembly function from a C-function ... there it is VERY important that whatever you do with the `ESP` and `EBP` registers is saved and restored to what the calling C-function would have expected from a "normal" C-function.